# Provider to a component that depends on value that returns from the server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that uses "MAT_DATE_FORMATS", the problem is that the "useValue" should be a value that returns from the server, is there a way to do that so the provider will be asynchronous?

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput:'YYYY-MM-DD',
        monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
    },
};

@Component({
    selector: 'esp-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
```

I need that "dateInput" will be a dynamic value from the server and not hard coded as here "YYYY-MM-DD".

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is not possible, both `useValue` and `useFactory` are synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly unfortunately this is not available.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279